# Caliburn.Micro HelloWindowManager Sample - View location not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

The HelloWindowManager Caliburn.Micro sample demonstrates displaying a Window (View) as Modal, Modeless or Popup and works just fine. However it has the views and Viewmodels in the project root so I wanted to tidy it up and have it use the default convention for view and view model locations, so I made the following changes:

1. Created a Views folder and moved both the ShellView.xaml and DialogView.xaml within it
2. Created a ViewModels folder and moved the matching View Models
3. Adjusted the namespace in the 4 files to reflect the move

On running the revised sample now I have the weird behaviour that while the 'Open Modal' button works perfectly, thus demonstrating that the View for the VM CAN be found, both the Open Modeless and the Open Popup buttons result in the message "Cannot find View for caliburn.Micro.HelloWindowmanager.ViewModels.DialogViewModel"

Any ideas?

Edited to add:

Absent any answers from anyone, I modified the sample to use the SimpleContainer instead of MEF - and it displays exactly the same behaviour as above.

e.g. This call works:
`var result = windowManager.ShowDialog(new DialogViewModel());`

but these two calls result in the 'cannot find view...' error message

```
windowManager.ShowWindow(new DialogViewModel(), "Modeless");
```

`windowManager.ShowPopup(new DialogViewModel(), "Popup", settings);`

Should I somehow be adding DialogViewModel to the SimpleContainer?

Comment: So just to make sure I have all the pieces. You have in thew Views Folder DialogView.xaml do you another folder within the Views folder called Dialog?

Comment: No. The code was taken directly from the working window manager sample downloaded from CodePlex. All I did was move the views and viewmodels from the root namespace to within views and viewmodels namespaces respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure my comment is the answer...

within the views folder you will all so need a folder called Dialog within that folder you will place Modeless.xaml and Popup.xaml both with of which need to have for example ".Views.Dialog.Modeless" as their namespace respectively.  Its a viewlocator drill that even I have fought with many times. :/

Note:  This just semantics you could put in the Namespace directly without the folder but from an organizational structure of the project it helps to understand it better.

Comment: OK I shall try that - but the point of the original sample code was to demonstrate Window Manager showing a View as a modal or modeless dialog, or as a popup, by simply invoking WindowManager in different ways for the SAME view. If the solution requires three seperate views to achieve that then the whole framework is less useful then I had hoped. I can make it work by moving everything back into the root namespace, but I don't want my project organised like that.

Comment: Look at the project source example in question, it does have the "primary" views in the root folder of project. There then is a dialog folder that holds the user controls Modeless and Popup. That is what is displayed to user from the DialogViewModel instantiation in window manager call. Just uses a view context specifier in this case instead of the DialogView in root. Just a repurposing of the viewmodal call in this case.  The logic isn't in the viewmodel but in the window manager.

Comment: You can do multi-view over single viewmodel with the framework very easily, the window manager wouldn't be my first go to for that need. If think about the example though you doing just that, single view model, multiview...

Comment: I see you thinking in terms of view-first development, the examples are for the most part viewmodel first.

Comment: No, I am always thinking of VM first development, so if I gave the impression I wanted View first then that was wrong.

Comment: Right - I see the Dialog folder in the sample now with the popup and modeless xaml within it. This is a classic case where one simple comment in the code sample would have made everything clear. I find it totally counterintuitive that the window manager calls in my original posting require that namespace to be satisfied, and saly, the documentation does not even hint that this is the case. Window Manager has NO proper documentation, just a link to an external site that does not work most of the time ...

Comment: ...and, when it does work, does not even begin to mention this weird 'rule' for the namespace and view names that must exist to use ShowWindow, ShowDialog and ShowPopup for the same VM! The bottom line is that it is my bad for failing to spot this anomaly in the original sammple, so thanks very much for taking the time to point this out for me. The rule I am taking away is that if a Context is supplied in the Window Manager calls, then the view must be in a sub-folder that matches the cut down VM name, with a xaml file that matches the context name.